# The table is not being created in the database

Tags: mysql

I created this code:

```
CREATE TABLE `pages`(
             `pageID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT= 2,
             `pageTITLE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
             `isROOT` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
             `pageCONTENT` text,
             PRIMARY KEY(`pageID`));


CREATE TABLE `player`(
             `playerID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT= 6,
             `userNAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
             `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
             PRIMARY KEY(`playerID`));


INSERT INTO `players`(`playerID`, `userNAME`, `password`) VALUES (1, 'admin',
             '21232F297A57A5A743894A0E4A801FC3');

INSERT INTO `pages`(`pageID`, `pageTITLE`, `isROOT`, `pageCONTENT`)
            VALUES(
             1,Főoldal,0,'<p>A létre hozás célja: </p>');
            (2,'Rólam',1,'<p>3 gyermek édesanyjaként deffiniálnám itt magam.</p>');
            (3,'Ötletek',1,'<p>Itt mindig a legújabb vagy legbeváltabb ötleteimet találod.</p>');
            (4,'Vélemények',1,'<p>Itt oszthatod meg a Te véleményed</p>');
            (5,'Kapcsolat',1,'<p>Várom visszajelzésed!</p>');
```

but it is not created in the two tables in the database!

I tried to paste just that in the database. In the SQL of Xampp directly integrated:

```
CREATE TABLE `pages`(
             `pageID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT= 2,
             `pageTITLE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
             `isROOT` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
             `pageCONTENT` text,
             PRIMARY KEY(`pageID`));


CREATE TABLE `player`(
             `playerID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT= 6,
             `userNAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
             `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
             PRIMARY KEY(`playerID`));
```

PHPMyAdmin out an error  in these lines:

```
`pageID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT= 2,
             `pageTITLE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
```

AND

```
`playerID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT= 6,
             `userNAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
```

Why? Now I began to learn , which is why I'm such a loss.

Comment: what you pasted isn't intended to work with PHP (that you tagged as) but in phpmyadmin or similar interface.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE player` then you're doing `INSERT INTO players` in its **plural** form. It's a **typo** and is **off-topic**.

Comment: Then seeing `password varchar(50)` - That tells me (**RED FLAG**) you're already doing something wrong, and using (or planning on using) an unsafe password hashing function or plain text and intending to build a login system; or just made it too short if you do plan on using something like [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Comment: Thank You for Fred